# Facebook friends list is empty

Tags: c#, facebook

My friends count result is `0`, why?

```
var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

dynamic me = client.Get("me");
string firstName = me.first_name;
string lastName = me.last_name;
MessageBox.Show(firstName);

dynamic friendListData = client.Get("/me/friends");

var result = (from i in (IEnumerable<dynamic>)friendListData.data
              select new
              {
                  i.name,
                  i.id
              }).ToArray();

ArrayList array = new ArrayList(result);

MessageBox.Show(array.Count.ToString());
```

Comment: Do you have any friends? ;)

Comment: ^  You walked into that one :)

Comment: Yeah you walked into that one :D What have you tried ?

Comment: Not compiles for me .net 4.5.1 ?

Answer (score 1):

If this is an app created after April 30, 2014 the only friends you will see are other friends who also use the app.

First, which version of the Graph API can you use?

> For apps created on or after April 30th 2014, making API calls without
>   specifying a version number is equivalent to calling v2.0 of the API.
>   These apps won't be able to call v1.0 of the API.

And how does API version affect the friends list?

> Graph API v2.0 includes some changes to how user IDs and friends work
>   in order to better protect people's info... In v2.0, the friends API
>   endpoint returns the list of a person's friends who are also using
>   your app. In v1.0, the response included all of a person's friends.

You can read it all here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading

Comment: OK, and for tag all friends on the post how i can do?

Comment: @user3369306 - if my response answers your question please accept it as the answer. Regarding tagging posts you should search to see if there's already an answer or create a new question.